# Display 0 value in hex file

Tags: java, hex

I am working on a hex file and display its content but if the value had "0". It did not appear when i print it out.

for example

```
 0 0 0 b7 7a 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 0 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20 f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 41 bc 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 1 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20 f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 53 3f 7b e5 db 40 2 0 c0 3 0 9 2 19 24 3d 0 22 68 1 db 9
```

Code

```
    String filename = "C:\\tm09888.123";
    FileInputStream in = null;
    int readHexFile = 0; 
    char hexToChar = ' ';
    String[] bytes = new String[10];

    try
    {            
        in = new FileInputStream(filename); 

        while((readHexFile = in.read()) != -1)
        {       
            if (Integer.toHexString(readHexFile).equals("f0"))
            {
                System.out.print("\n\n\n");
            }
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(readHexFile) + " ");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(NARSSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  

}
```

When I printed out the file the "0"s did not appear and values such as "c0" became "c".

How I do i rewrite the code to display the "0"s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When display it on the screen "0" values did not appear and value like "c0" become only "c"

I suspect it's more likely that "0c" becomes just "c". I'd expect "c0" to be fine.

The problem is that you're using `Integer.toHexString` which will only use as many digits as it needs to. You could *manually* fix this by writing:

```
if (readHexFile < 0x10) {
    System.out.print("0");
}
```

Alternatively, just use:

```
private static final char[] HEX_DIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
...
System.out.print(HEX_DIGITS[readHexFile >> 4]);
System.out.print(HEX_DIGITS[readHexFile % 15]);
System.out.print(" ");
```

Or even more simply:

```
System.out.printf("%02x ", readHexFile);
```

Also note that there's no need to convert to a hex string to compare with `0xf0`. You can use:

```
if (readHexFile == 0xf0) {
    System.out.print("\n\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Integer.toHexString` doesn't guarantee returning a two-digit result.

If you want it to always be two digits, you could use `String.format` instead:

```
System.out.print(String.format("%02x ", readHexFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say what the problem is with the code, but it seems things would be much clearer if you used Scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String s = sc.next();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```